# Ternary Operator on a response in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ternary-operator

Am working on a Laravel app whereby I get response of date which has a negative (meaning it was days ago) and plain date (no negative meaning days in the future)  e.g **-140** days means 140 days ago and **140** days means 140 days to come.

On the view am trying to create a Regex and a ternary operator whereby if the response has a negative before it,,, I should remove the negative sign before and append days ago after it. For instance **-140 should change to 140 days ago** and **140 should change to 140 days**.

**Logic**

```
public function allRenewal()
{
    //Fetch response from the API
    $life = GeneralHelper::global_Curl([], 'api/v1/b2b/life/agent-policies')->data;

    //Sort all in descdending order acccording to days left  
    $lifeSort = collect($life)->sortBy('days_left');

    //dd($lifeSort);

    return view('B2B::pages.renewals', ['lifePol' => $lifeSort]);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($lifePol as $life_d)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$life_d->days_left}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Why not use `Carbon::diffForHumans()` as it's already integrated in Laravel? https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: Thanks,, would you mind explaining via the example I gave above?

Comment: This is what either a minus or plus value ? `$life_d->days_left`

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen The variable **$life_d** is the response from the backend and days_left if the days which comes either in negative format (meaning days ago) or plain meaning the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<td>{{ $life_d->days_left < 0 ? ($life_d->days_left * -1) . ' days ago' : $life_d->days_left  . ' days' }}</td>
```

Please note `$life_d->days_left == 0` is not considered here.

Fiddle : https://implode.io/SW1ib9

Comment: `$life_d->days_left` will always return a value right ?

Comment: Oooh,, Apologies,, I had edited the wrong codebase,, It works fine..Thanks alot